# Calendar with ASP.NET MVC, C#, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar, textbox

I want to add a calendar that only shows when I click the textbox and when I select the date, it adds to the text; the format needs to be dd/mm/yyyy.

Can anyone help me?

```
<input id="dateRangeS1" name="dateRangeS1" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: try any JS plugin with Calendar object. Like Datepicker in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<input id="dateRangeS1" name="dateRangeS1" type="date" value="">
```